# why servlet shows internal errors 500

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

pass the value from jsp to servlet.while bring me internal error 500. When passing the value between jsp and servlet.
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1"
java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)
java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
servlets.guessGame.doPost(guessGame.java:20)
servlets.guessGame.doGet(guessGame.java:81)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:502)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
I don't know why it happens Is there any way to fix these errors?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<%@ page import="model.GuessNumber" %>
<%
    GuessNumber minimum = new GuessNumber(1);
    GuessNumber maximum = new GuessNumber(11);

    GuessNumber guessNum = new GuessNumber();
    guessNum.setRandom(minimum.getValue(), maximum.getValue());

    GuessNumber guesses = new GuessNumber(1);
%>

<html>
<body>
    <h1>Guessing Game</h1>
    <p>Welcome! Lets begin the game!</p>
    <p>Please guess a number between <%= minimum.getValue() %> and  <%= maximum.getValue() %>.</p>
        <form name="GuessNumForm" action="guessGame" method="get">
            <label>
                Guess <%= guesses.getValue() %> :
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="guess" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" name="guessButton" value="Guess"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="minimum" value=" <%= minimum.getValue() %>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="maximum" value=" <%= maximum.getValue() %>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="guessNum" value=" <%= guessNum.getValue() %>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="guesses" value=" <%= guesses.getValue() %>" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>

package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import model.GuessNumber;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/guessGame"})
public class guessGame extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int guessInt = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("guess"));
        GuessNumber guess = new GuessNumber(guessInt);

        GuessNumber minimum = new GuessNumber(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("minimum")));
        GuessNumber maximum = new GuessNumber(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("maximum")));

        int guessNumInt = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("guessNum"));
        GuessNumber guessNum = new GuessNumber(guessNumInt);
        int guessesInt = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("guesses"));
        GuessNumber guesses = new GuessNumber(guessesInt);

        int score = 100;
        int decrement = 10;
        //int totalScore = 0;
        String msg = " ";

        if(guess.getValue() == guessNum.getValue()) {
            msg = "Congratulations, you got it in" + guesses.getValue() + "tries. Your score is" ;

        } else {
            guesses.increment();
            //totalScore = score - decrement;
            if(guesses.getValue() < 10) {
                if(guess.getValue()< guessNum.getValue()) {
                    msg ="Incorrect. the number is higher than " + guess.getValue();
                }else {
                    msg ="Incorrect. the number is lower than " + guess.getValue();
                }
            } else {
                msg ="You lose game." + "Your score is ";
            }
        }
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<!DOC-TYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<meta charset='US-ASCII'>");
        out.println("<title>Guessing number Game</title>");
        out.println("</head>");

        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Guessing Game</h1>");
        out.println("<p>"+ msg +"</p>");

        if(guess.getValue() == guessNum.getValue()) {
            out.println("<a href='index.jsp'>Play again!</a>");
        } else {
            out.println("<p>Please guess a number between" + minimum.getValue() + "and" + maximum.getValue() + ">.</p>");
            out.println("<form name='GuessNumForm' action='/GuessGame' method='post'>");
            out.println("<label>Guess" + guesses.getValue() + ":</label>");
            out.println("<input type='text' name='guess' value=''/>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' name='guessButton' value='Guess'/>");
            out.println("<input type='hidden' name='minimum' value=" + minimum.getValue() + " />");
            out.println("<input type='hidden' name='maximum' value=" + maximum.getValue() + " />");
            out.println("<input type='hidden' name='guessNum' value=" + guessNum.getValue() + " />");
            out.println("<input type='hidden' name='guesses' value=" + guesses.getValue() + "/>");
            out.println("</form>");
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.doPost(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: There’s an extra space character in the front

Comment: Yup.  The error message says `For input string: " 1"`.  Note the space.

Comment: I can't really figure it out where the space from

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="foo" value=" <%= foo.getValue() %>"` <- how about here inside `value`?

Answer (score 0):

Little correction in your JSP code:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="minimum" value=" <%= minimum.getValue() %>" />
```

Should be (Space between value= tag):

```
 <input type="hidden" name="minimum" value="<%= minimum.getValue() %>" />
```

Little explanation:
Assuming an Integer value- ' 1' is not a valid Integer right? '1' is thus the changes.

Correct it for every Input tag.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: This answer doesn't help. The changes are useless if the user submits wrong values. The problem should be resolved on the server and notify the user about error.